# format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat] in C language when typing scanf("%d", (*(pArr[i])).age);

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, structure

I have a program where I have to add a name, age and 2 courses for a student in a database using pointer structures and pointer arrays in C. I am able to store the name entered by the user into the database but not the age. When I enter age, this error shows up "format specifies type 'int *' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
scanf("%d", (*(pArr[i])).age);"

I know that this could be a common error but I am a bit new to C. Any help would be appreciated.
My function for entering new values looks like:-

Also, this code is still in development, so please point me out any extra errors if there are :)

```
//global
#define SIZE 30
#define fieldLength 200

struct db_type
{
   char name[fieldLength];
   int age;
   char course1[fieldLength];
   char course2[fieldLength];
   char status[fieldLength];
 };

struct courseInfo
{ 
  char code [20]; // e.g., EECS2030
  char title [fieldLength];
  char  date [20];
  char time_start [20];
  char time_end [20];
  char  location [20]; 
};

struct courseInfo courseArr[SIZE]; 

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    
    struct db_type * db_pArr[SIZE];  // main db storage

    init_list(db_pArr);  // set to NULL
    
    init_courseArr();  // load course from diskfile
    
    char choice;
    for(; ;){
      choice = prompt_menu();
      switch (choice)
      {
         case 'n': enterNew(db_pArr); break;  
         case 'q': exit(1); // terminate the whole program
       }
    
     }
     return 0;
}

void enterNew(struct db_type * pArr[SIZE]){ 
  static int i=0; 
  static int j=0;
  int flag = 0;

  pArr[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct db_type));

  printf("name: ");
  scanf("%s", (*pArr[i]).name);

  printf("age: ");
  scanf("%d", (*(pArr[i])).age); //error here

  printf("course-1: ");
  scanf("%s", (*pArr[i]).course1);

  while(flag == 0)
  for(int j=0; j<SIZE; j++){
    if(strcmp((*pArr[i]).course1, courseArr[j].code) == 1 && flag == 0){
      printf("course does not exist, enter again: \n");
      printf("course-1: ");
      scanf("%s", (*pArr[i]).course1);
    }
    else
      flag = 1;
  }

  if(flag == 1)
    ++i;

  // further code in development
  // printf("course-2: ");
  // scanf("%s", pArr[i].course2);
}
```

*Further extra information about what program does*
-> This program basically is a part of a student database management system. When user enters 'n' or 'N', this function is invoked. User has the option to enter student name, age, student's course-1 and course-2. It also has to check whether course-1 and course-2's start time and end time clash or not and store it in a variable called char status[] of structure db_type.

Comment: `(*pArr[i]).name` can be rewritten as `pArr[i]->name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  scanf("%d", (*(pArr[i])).age);
```

to

```
  scanf("%d", &(*(pArr[i])).age);
```

scanf() requires a pointer to the variable and adding `&` in front of it returns the pointer of the variable.

Comment: Thank you. It was a simple error in the end.

Comment: @Nzed No problem :)